# TensorFlow: XLA not running with "Invalid argument: No _XlaCompile" errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I'm trying out the XLA tutorial described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit

I'm running `mnist_softmax_xla.py` from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax_xla.py with the following options:

`TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=2 TF_XLA_FLAGS='--xla_generate_hlo_graph=.*' python mnist_softmax_xla.py`

Unfortunately I get a bunch of "Custom creator error: Invalid argument: No _XlaCompile for Const" errors in the output (and same for every other type of op).  Also, no hlo_graph_xx.dot files are created (as the tutorial says should be).

My python install is Anaconda 4.3.1 (Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

TensorFlow is version 1.1.0 compiled from source with the following commands:

```
$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
$ curl https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bazel

$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
$ cd tensorflow/
$ git checkout v1.1.0
$ ./configure 

Please specify the location of python. [Default is /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python]: 
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 
Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? [Y/n] 
jemalloc enabled
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] 
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] 
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N] y
XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages]

Using python library path: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] 
No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] 
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Configuration finished
............
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --expunge_async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
...........
INFO: All external dependencies fetched successfully.

$ bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
$ pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Why does XLA not work with this setup?

How do I install TensorFlow with working XLA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The reason for this is a little obscure note in the XLA tutorial:

> Note: Turning on JIT at the session level will not result in
>   operations being compiled for the CPU. JIT compilation for CPU
>   operations must be done via the manual method documented below. This
>   decision was made due to the CPU backend being single-threaded.

This doesn't work with CPU:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
...
```

This works on CPU (and GPU as well):

```
jit_scope = tf.contrib.compiler.jit.experimental_jit_scope
with jit_scope():
    ...
```